# Can't use filled layer with ggspectro seewave

Tags: r, ggplot2, spectrogram

I am trying to create a nice spectrogram using `ggplot2` and `seewave`. But I am having issues with the geom polygon layer (I think). Trying to change to a different layer results in an error at the bottom. The goal is to have a smooth looking spectrogram if there is a different solution than the one I am going for please let me know

`event_data$rad` is a basic vector, `pal` is a colourRampPalette

The basic raw output with a `geom_tile()` layer using amplitude is

```
v <- seewave::ggspectro(event_data$rad, f = 500, flim = c(0, 0.12)) + 
   geom_tile(aes(fill = amplitude)) +
   scale_fill_gradientn(name="Amplitude\n(dB)\n", limits=c(-115,0), colours = pal(115))
```

[image: goem_tile output of ggspectro]

I am trying to create a smoother-looking spectrogram with the below

```
v <- seewave::ggspectro(event_data$rad, f = 500, flim = c(0, 0.12)) + 
   stat_contour(geom="polygon", aes(fill=..level..), bins = 115) +
   scale_fill_gradientn(name="Amplitude\n(dB)\n", limits=c(-115,0), colours = pal(115))
```

[image: Stat_contour with geom polygon plot]

I am trying to use the `stat_contour_filled()` layer to remove the transparent areas. Which are gaps between polygons from my understanding. However, I get an "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" output. When running a `traceback()` the output is

```
> traceback()
16: stop("Discrete value supplied to continuous scale", call. = FALSE)
15: scales::train_continuous(x, self$range)
14: f(..., self = self)
13: self$range$train(x)
12: f(..., self = self)
11: self$train(df[[aesthetic]])
10: f(..., self = self)
9: scale$train_df(df = df)
8: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
7: lapply(scales$scales, function(scale) scale$train_df(df = df))
6: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
5: lapply(data, scales_train_df, scales = npscales)
4: ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
3: ggplot_build(x)
2: print.ggplot(v)
1: print(v)
```

After some digging the `ggplot_build` output, I think `self$range` being passed is -100 so I'm not sure that the `stat_contour_filled()` layer will work with `seewave::ggspectro` output, without manually overriding the value

If there is some other output I am missing let me know

Comment: Can't say for sure without having access to your data, but what happens if you replace the `geom_tile(aes(fill = amplitude))` line in the basic version with `geom_raster(aes(fill = amplitude), interpolate = TRUE)`? Does that achieve the smoothness you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's toward what I was going for. But just seems a bit Blurry compared to the contour plot. Couldn't find a way to adjust the interpolation